# Output with curly braces

Tags: go

I wrote simple function to find and return random name from a CSV file, where names are just a names written in capital letters. It works pretty well, but output is given in curly braces even if it is as a type of string. Anybody has an idead how to get rid of those curly braces?

```
func chosname(filePath string) string {
    var persons []Person
    rName := rand.Intn(1000) + 1000
    isFirstRow := true
    headerMap := make(map[string]int)

    f, _ := os.Open(filePath)
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    
    for {
        // Read row
        record, err := r.Read()
        // Stop at EOF.
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        checkError("Some other error occurred", err)

        if isFirstRow {
            isFirstRow = false
            for _, v := range record {
                headerMap[v] = 0
            }
            continue
        }

        persons = append(persons, Person{
            IMIEPIERWSZE: record[headerMap["IMIEPIERWSZE"]],
        })
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", persons[rName])
}
```

Output:
`{PAUL}`
Wanted output: `PAUL`

Comment: Note that the curly braces are there because that's the `fmt` package's default formatting of **struct values**, and you *are* printing an instance of the `Person` struct. For more details on the formatting, read the package's [documentation on "Printing"](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.18.4#hdr-Printing).

Comment: That's how structs are formatter, either print `fmt.Println("%s", persons[rName].IMIEPIERWSZE)` (the actual string field of the struct), or implement the String method as suggested un @HamzaAnis's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces will be printed out because of the default formatting and there are some several workarounds around that but the best of that would be to implement the `String() string` method to the `Person` type and add the custom formats as you need.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    IMIEPIERWSZE string
}

func (p Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", p.IMIEPIERWSZE)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Person{"test"})
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/gfnY_gn1kJ2

Comment: Why just not `return p.IMIEPIERWSZE` instead of `return fmt.Sprintf("%s", p.IMIEPIERWSZE)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can also call the property of a person while printing

```
return fmt.Sprintf("%s", persons[rName].Name)
```

the curly braces are printing because of you are printing a struct.
You can either choose the above answer @Hamza Anis mentioned with a custom formating or if you just want to print the name of the person you can just follow this method.